# Negative index on nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

Let's say I've got a nested list like this:

```
mylist = [[],[],[]]
```

and I want to insert elements at the end of the second nested list:

```
mylist[1].insert(-1, 1)
mylist[1].insert(-1, 2)
```

The output i expected was:

```
[[], [1, 2], []]
```

but instead I got:

```
[[], [2, 1], []]
```

Can somebody explain this to me? I thought the index -1 always pointed to the last position of a list.

Comment: If you want to add something to the _end_ of a list, use `append`. Using `insert(-1, ` will insert something into the position of the current last element (which means it will push the last element up and become the next-to-last element).

Comment: That totally explains it, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a list has for example 3 elements, they are numbered from 0 to 2 (i.e. `0, 1, 2`).

If you want use negative indices, they are numbered from -3 to -1 (i.e. `-3, -2, -1`).

Now, if you want insert a new element at position `-1`, it is the same, as inserting at position `2`, i.e. the inserted element will become `element[2]`.

But `element[2]` will be then an element of the **4-element list**, so its current position in the negative notation is not `-1` but `-2`:

```
element[-4], element[-3], element[-2], element[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

according to documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), the first argument of the insert method is the index of the element *before* which to insert...and -1 designates the last element of a list: so by calling insert(-1,...) the element you insert will always become the next to last element of your list.

this is easy to veryfy. if you insert yet another element

```
mylist[1].insert(-1, 3)
```

you will notice the resulting list becomes

```
[[], [2, 3, 1], []]
```

so should probably use append instead. or calculate the index dynamically like

```
mylist[1].insert(len(mylist[1]), 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this page](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/insert),

`list.insert(index, element)` means you insert `element` at index `index`. `.insert(-1, value)` means inserting `value` at the last element of the list (`index=len(lst)-1`). So

```
mylist[1].insert(1, 1)
mylist[1].insert(1, 2)
```

should solve the problem.

Another approach is to use `append` as the other one said.

```
mylist[1].append(1)
mylist[1].append(2)
```